# Authenticate Multiple Private Channels in One Authentication call in pusher.com

Tags: php, authentication, python-2.7, pusher

I have multiple private channels to subscribe and each channels goes through pusher authentication process. 
I want to know that it is possible to call pusher authentication one time for all private channels.

Comment: I found the following: [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9dtifpLithoJ:pusher.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/852-authenticate-multiple-private-channels-in-one-post-request+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de) "We don't presently have multi auth support within our client library but it is on our backlog."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** This is now possible via a plugin:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#batching-auth-requests-aka-multi-auth

---

This is a feature that has been requested a number of times (I used to work for Pusher and handle the majority of support requests). However, it's something that you **cannot** presently do with any of the Pusher client libraries.

I'd recommend that you contact Pusher support and let them know you require this feature and why (probably because you're subscribing to many channels and right now this results to a high number of HTTP calls to your auth endpoint).

Comment: thanks.I have sent mail to Pusher support regarding this. Lets see what would be their reply.

Comment: @user3048148 I have same problem, did You get any response from Pusher? If You have a solution could You share it with community?

Comment: @Misiu This answer now points to a pusher-js [plugin](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#batching-auth-requests-aka-multi-auth) that makes this possible.